react-navigation v6: Prevent scaling down screen when open modal
Is it possible to turn off scaling down the parent screen when opening a modal using @react-navigation/native-stack?
Check my code below please:
const RootNavigator = () => {
   return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={'Home'} screenOptions=. 
         {SCREEN_OPTION}>
         {SCREENS.map(screen => (
         <Stack.Screen
         key={screen.name}
         name={screen.name as keyof RootStackParamList}
         component={screen.component}
         options={screen.options}
       />
     ))}
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Modal"
    component={ModalStackView}
    options={{
      headerShown: false,
      presentation: 'modal',
      contentStyle: {
        backgroundColor: `${COLORS.primary}10`,
      },
    }}
  />
 </Stack.Navigator>
);
};

I tried to find any props in official docs with no hope:
offical link
Any help is appreciated.
